# How can labeling/2 generate solutions starting from the midpoint of a domain?

Tags: prolog, clpfd, labeling

Having a list with independent variables, whose domain is 1..N, how can we use labeling/2 so it starts producing solutions starting from the middle?

The flags i tried are [bisect], [enum], [max], [min], [ff], but no matter which i picked, i can't make it work.

My code is:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

combos(EMPLOYEES,POSTS,LIST):-
   LIMIT is POSTS-EMPLOYEES+1,
   length(LIST,EMPLOYEES),
   LIST ins 1..LIMIT,
   sum(LIST,#=,POSTS),
   labeling([bisect],LIST).
```

after setting a query, for example:

```
?-combos(2,10,LIST).
```

i want it to return:

```
L = [5,5];
L = [4,6];
L = [6,4] ...
```

instead of:

```
L = [1,9];
L = [2,8];
L = [3,7] ...
```

Comment: Downvoted because TimzyPatzy  changed the question after answers have been posted which made answers invalid. TimzyPatzy should have accepted posted answers and post a different question.

Comment: I agree with @false, this is a completely different question! You are not just being more "specific" about your original question, as you said. Your chanigng it comlpetely! Even the example in your original question contradicts what you added as being more specific!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, whenever you try to extend the functionality of clpfd, try to reuse as much as possible. It seems that you want solutions first whose sum of distances to the center is as small as possible.

```
combos2(EMPLOYEES,POSTS,LIST):-
   LIMIT is POSTS-EMPLOYEES+1,
   length(LIST,EMPLOYEES),
   LIST ins 1..LIMIT,
   sum(LIST,#=,POSTS),
   Mid is (LIMIT+1) div 2,           %%
   maplist(dist(Mid), LIST, DISTS),  %%    
   sum(DISTS,#=,Totaldist),          %%
   labeling([],[Totaldist|LIST]).

dist(Mid, E, D) :-
    D #= abs(Mid-E).

?- combos2(2,10,L).
   L = [5,5]
;  L = [4,6]
;  L = [6,4]
;  L = [3,7]
;  L = [7,3]
;  ... .
```

Comment: To be specific, i want to distribute POSTS as evenly as possible to EMPLOYEES, so, for example, query: ?-  combos(5,21,L) should return as a first solution: L = [4,4,4,4,5].

Comment: Ok, but you are changing your requirements. Replace `dist/2` by: `dist(Mid, E, D) :-
    D #= (Mid-E)^2.`

Comment: Then check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
combos(2,S,L) :- b2(S,L).
combos(C,S,[A|L]) :-
    C > 2,
    b2(S,[A,B]),
    D is C-1,
    combos(D,B,L).

b2(S,L) :- B is S-1, bisector(B,L).

bisector(Y,[A,B]) :-
    odd(Y),
    M is div(1+Y,2),
    Z is M-1,
    range(D,0,Z),
    bisec1(D,M,A,B).
bisector(Y,[A,B]) :-
    even(Y),
    M is 1+Y,
    Z is Y/2-1,
    range(D,0,Z),
    bisec2(D,M,A,B).

bisec1(0,M,M,M).
bisec1(D,M,A,B) :- D > 0, A is M + D, A > 0, B is M - D, B > 0.
bisec1(D,M,A,B) :- D > 0, A is M - D, A > 0, B is M + D, B > 0.

bisec2(D,M,A,B) :- A is (M+2*D+1)/2, A > 0, B is (M-2*D-1)/2, B > 0.
bisec2(D,M,A,B) :- A is (M-2*D-1)/2, A > 0, B is (M+2*D+1)/2, B > 0.

even(X) :- 0 is mod(X, 2).
odd(X) :- 1 is mod(X, 2).

range(M,M,_).
range(X,M,N) :- P is M + 1, P =< N, range(X,P,N).
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. By midpoint, i meant returning solutions in such a way that each variable has about the same value with the other variables on the list. So a question like: ?- combos(4,16,LIST) should return: LIST = [4,4,4,4], then LIST = [4,4,3,5], and so on.